# Recursive page fault handler

Tags: c++, linux, operating-system, virtual-memory

I have a conceptual question regarding operating systems and page fault handlers.  Let us consider the case when the kernel has a virtual address space.  So if there is a page fault and the execution jumps to the page fault handler.  And if the stack for the execution of the page fault handler causes a page fault what happens then?

Comment: I can't answer your question completely, but the kernel itself has full reign over memory, and can ensure that vital routines like this are not paged to disk. In fact, you can lock pages in a userspace application using [mlock](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html).

Comment: Wow I had no clue mlock existed! Thank you for telling me that!! So there is a reserved stack for each handler in the interrupt vector table?

Comment: @Curious: There's no reserved stack for the handlers. They're always in physical memory and never paged out. They're in kernel space, not user space.

Comment: But what if the stack of execution for the routine grows to the point where it gets to a portion of memory that is mapped to a virtual address for some other process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if the stack for the execution of the page fault handler causes a page fault what happens then?

There is no reserved stack for the handlers.

The page fault handling routine is part of the operating system kernel, and therefore in kernel space. Even though kernel memory is still organized into pages, these pages remain resident in physical memory and do not get swapped out to disk. Things that get swapped out to disk are in user space. As such, since kernel memory does not get swapped out, page faults would not be generated while the kernel is trying to handle a page fault.

This makes sense if you think about it. The kernel would be unable to handle any page faults if the code to handle page faults were to require a page fault handler to get itself back into physical memory. It'd be unable to do so.

In principle, if we still try to assume your scenario, then I'd think that the kernel would:

- need to become more complicated in order to handle this case you brought up;
- not be able to work with or support virtual address spaces and/or swap memory;
- would crash as soon as the first page fault takes place (e.g. probably a kernel panic)

Comment: Sorry I posted a comment above, ill just copy it here also - But what if the stack of execution for the routine grows to the point where it gets to a portion of memory that is mapped to a virtual address for some other process?

Comment: @Curious: I'm not sure I follow your question. I think you might be mixing a few things. The virtual addresses are mapped to physical addresses, not the other way around. Ultimately, if a major mess that cannot be handled were to take place inside the kernel, then it's likely you'd get unpredictable behavior, a deadlock, or in the worst case a panic. This [osdev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Paging) might be useful for you.

Comment: Sorry about not being clear! This is what I meant - Suppose process A accesses memory at memory location 4000 and then there is a page fault, execution switches to the page fault handler (assume in this scheme that we have a kernel with a virtual address space), now when the page fault handler is running, and it increments the stack pointer and stores something on the stack at address 4020, there is another page fault. What happens then?

Comment: @Curious: If I understand you correctly, I don't think that situation can happen. The kernel code is in memory pages, but they remain resident in physical memory, i.e., it does not get swapped out to disk. (Imagine if the code responsible for handling page faults were itself to be swapped out!) But, for the sake of your question, if we assume your scenario, I think the kernel would either need to become more complex to slowly handle your case (e.g. only some carefully-selected portions allowed to be swapped out), or likely crash in some way.

Comment: @Curious: Is there something you think I've left unanswered or that is probably not as clear?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I hadn't logged in to stack overflow for the past few days.  I had asked another question because I felt that I worded this one wrong.  I got a contradictory answer there.  Could you help me in understanding what really happens? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35071738/which-stack-does-the-page-fault-handler-in-an-operating-system-run-on

Comment: @Curious: The different wording on the new question makes things different and makes me have a different (and not so clear) understanding relative to this one. That being said, the accepted answer there doesn't seem to be that much different from mine here; i.e. the concept is the same: the kernel is generally prepared to handle the situation. It also pointed out the user/kernel space distinction I mentioned here. However, it doesn't seem to deal with the page fault within a page fault point you seemed to be interested in. Re-editing might be more appropriate than re-posting, though.

Comment: Sorry about that I didn't know reediting would send notifications to the people following this post! I should have edited this instead...